# Adding controls and column in database dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamic

I have created a form which consists of html form elements. I want to give user an option to edit or add form elements to that form and store value in database on submit in MVC.

Creating control dynamically is ok but I have no idea how to add column to existing table in database using entity framework in MVC.

How do i create a new column in existing table ? or is there any other approach to this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Think differently**,its not an right approach to create new column to existing table for dynamically form and save data.. even try to do this by save data in row wise w.r.t. each form in tables

Comment: Your database tables should describe your ability to create dynamic forms. Your dynamic forms should not describe how to create your database. Take a step back and think about restructuring your database to accommodate all of the different types of forms. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Configuration;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace BindDataControl_Demo  
{  
    public partial class GridView : System.Web.UI.Page  
    {  
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (!IsPostBack)  
            {  
                BindGridView();  
            }  
        }  
        private void BindGridView()  
        {  
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;  
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))  
            {  
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetProductList", con);  
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
                con.Open();  
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
                GridView1.DataBind();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it?

Comment: This does not answer the question. While probably a good starting point, we are looking for specific answers to the specific question asked.